# Combine Dockerfiles on build

Tags: docker

I use **docker** for both a development and a production environment.

Currently, I have two `Dockerfile` :

**dev.dockerfile** :

```
FROM image:latest

[common code in dev and production, e.g. : RUN apt-get install php5]
```

**prod.dockerfile** :

```
FROM image:latest

[common code in dev and production, e.g. : RUN apt-get install php5]

[code only used in production, e.g. : RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache]
```

What I want is to merge the common code to a file **common.dockerfile**, and then be able to build my *dev or production* image with the running of only one `docker` command.

Do you have any idea on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set an environment variable when building prod. Let prod RUN statements be noop unless variable set.

Comment: That's a great answer that totally do the job. Sorry for this late approval :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest inheriting production image from dev image, example:

dev.dockerfile stays unchanged, and prod.dockerfile will look like:

```
FROM <dev_image_name_and_tag>

[code only used in production, e.g. : RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache]
```

Comment: I would have to run two `docker build` commands, is it right ? It would be great if I could do something like `FROM common.dockerfile`, and then `docker build` would build both images.

Comment: Well I don't think it will be possible. With my approach your images will be also built faster because common packages will be installed only once in dev image.